# Giving cron permission to execute command

Tags: raspberry-pi, ruby, modprobe

I'm trying to get a ruby script to run via cron. The cron job looks like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/shed_watcher/lib/shed_watcher.rb >> /tmp/cron_shed_watcher.log 2>&1
```

I've encountered a couple of problems. The first was that the environment cron runs in could find one of the required gems:

```
require "rest_client"
```

This was solved by setting the `GEM_PATH` in the crontab:

```
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
```

The second problem is that the script, running on Occidentals on a Raspberry Pi, makes use of a temperature probe and needs to call:

```
`modprobe w1-gpio`
`modprobe w1-therm`
```

i.e. `modprobe` commands in backticks. Cron cannot execute this, instead I get an "operation not permitted" message. `modprobe` is found in `/sbin` so I added a path entry to my crontab:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:....
```

But I get the same error (not surprising as it was a "not permitted" message, not a "not found" message). What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: What if you just added your modprobes to rc.local or similar to run it once at boot time.

Comment: That's a good idea, although I'd prefer the script to not rely on another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your job to the root's crontab, not the user's one. User's crontabs always executed with uid/gid of the user when root crontab can contain additional field:

```
* * * * * username /path/to/the/command
```

Then command will be executed with `username` privileges/permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked although I didn't need to add a username

Comment: It works as root if no username placed, cause root hasn't restrictions. But for security reasons you have to set appropriate uid - possibly `www`.

Comment: Hmmm.... I didn't set a uid

Comment: Crontab owner always assumed when username omitted. Root can change to privileges to some other user while nonprivileged users can't.